# The reflection and the reflexion

Tags: differences

Is the  reflexion concerning of the humans only and not of the robots which are  reflective only?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: A dictionary might help here. I'm not sure that there are distributional differences dependent on sense for the spelling variations.

Comment: It's just an (unusual) spelling variation.  Some people may use it in specific cases, but it's so rare that it would be difficult to establish a pattern.

Comment: Notably, the spelling was mainly used prior to about 1850, when standardized spelling began to take hold.  Up to that time I see it used in a lot of physics texts.